# Showing that an integer function's value and the EOF value are not the same

Tags: c, programming-challenge

I was doing Exercise 1.6 and 1.7 in 'The C Programming Language' by K&R.

The questions state: **"Verify that the experssion getchar() != EOF is 0 or 1"** (Exercise 1.6) and **"Write a program to print the value of EOF"** (Exercise 1.7)

Here is my attempt at trying to do both in one program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d \t This is the value of EOF \n", EOF);
    int c = getchar() != EOF;
    printf("%d \t This is the value of getchar(), our variable \n", c);
}
```

I was wondering if there is a more concise or preferred way to do this?

Comment: _`int c = getchar() != EOF;`_ Doesn't do what you think it does. `c` will only contain `0` or `1`, but not what was read from input.

Comment: Actually,, in this instance, @πάνταῥεῖ the code is right according to the requirements, but the string printed is misleading (not enough to be not-working code)

Comment: @rolfl As is that code won't work like intended, did I miss something?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - the code is supposed to print out the result of `getchar() != EOF`, and it is not supposed to print out the value of `getChar()`. The message should say something like `This is the value of getchar() != EOF` instead of `This is the value of getchar()`

Comment: @rolfl _`"This is the value of getchar() != EOF"`_ as it doesn't do this it's not working as intended. Sorry for nitpicking.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - I copied the code, compiled it, ran it, entered `ctrl-D` to give an EOF, and it prints `0        This is the value of getchar(), our variable`. I then ran it again and typed a key (`g`) and it output; `1        This is the value of getchar(), our variable` which is what the spec requires: ***"Verify that the experssion getchar() != EOF is 0 or 1"***

Answer (score 3):

The original code from this question improperly assumes that `c` still has the numeric value of a character, saying "This is the value of getchar()".  This is not actually true based upon that code.  The value being printed out in the last line is not the value of `getchar()` but the value of the comparison of `getchar` against `!= EOF`.

To clarify things, I wrote the below code, with comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
  /* result variables, with initial value for cleanliness */
  int getchar_result = 0;
  int compare_result = 0;

  /* print out the value of EOF as an integer */
  printf( "%d \t This is the value of EOF \n", EOF );

  /* obtaining the result of getchar */
  getchar_result = getchar();

  /* obtaining the result of comparison */
  compare_result = EOF != getchar_result;

  /* print out the actual value of the getchar_result, which may or may not be EOF */
  printf( "%d \t This is the value of getchar()\n", getchar_result );

  /* print out the value of the comparison result against EOF */
  printf( "%d \t This Is the result of (getchar()!=EOF)\n", compare_result);
}
```

This produced the results, when <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> was entered during the execution the first round, and 1 was entered during the second.  Notice that the comparison value is zero (not true) in the first, and 1 (true) in the second.

```
UbuntuPrompt>./a.out
-1       This is the value of EOF
-1       This is the value of getchar()
0        This Is the result of (getchar()!=EOF)
UbuntuPrompt>./a.out
-1       This is the value of EOF
1
49       This is the value of getchar()
1        This Is the result of (getchar()!=EOF)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, nowhere in the question does it assume that the system uses __ASCII__.  I'd re-word that first sentence to simply say *numeric character code* or something.

Comment: interesting point. the man-page for getchar doesn't say ascii, but just says character.   I have yet to see a computer that didn't use ascii for a character, but I suppose, technically, you are correct.